# Using sender to identify object that called method in ios

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm new at this so thanks in advance for any help here.

I'm just playing around with a little exercise in iOS and I have 2 different things calling the same routine.

Each of these message calls passes along sender. One of these is a `UIButton` that calls when `touchUpInside`, one is a `UISegmentedControl` that calls when `valueChanges`.

I need to handle the initial part slightly differently within the same method and i know that somehow I use sender.

What I need to do is to ask if sender is a `UIButton` or if sender is a `UISegmentedControl`.

I tried

```
if  ([sender isKindOfClass:UISegmentedControl]) { ... }
```

And

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:UIButton]) { ... }
```

Both throw up an error along like this one:

`Unexpected interface name "UIButton": expected expression`

So that's obviously wrong.

Comment: Since these are two different types of controls, I would strongly consider having them point to different functions, and then move the code that **is** common into a different routine that you can call from both of those functions.  I like to keep the code segregated so that it is nice and easy to follow....

Comment: Agreed with @lnafziger;  in general, use of `isKindOfClass:` to implement different behaviors is both uncommon and discouraged.   Far better to have different, explicit, paths of execution with the common code factored out.   Pointer comparison (as Hot Licks described below) is more palatable, but still a bit obtuse compared to simply having a separate outlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[sender isKindOfClass:UISegmentedControl]
```

Should be:

```
[sender isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]
```

Comment: @SimonTheDiver If this answer helped you be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also simply compare `sender` to the IBOutlet variable that links to the UI object. Or you can give your UI objects `tag`s and test `sender.tag`.

Comment: +1, I like comparing pointers directly if possible. It's clearer, and technically faster.

Comment: The advantage on using the tag is that if several senders should be handled identically you can use the same tag for all of them.